# Сделать дважды fetch_array из одной выборки

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Доброго времени! Делаю выборку из БД например вот:

```
 $db = new mysqli($bdserver,$bduser,$bdpassword,$bdname);
 $db->set_charset("utf8");
 $tmpy = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT year FROM rtes ORDER BY year DESC");
 $numy = $tmpy->num_rows;

 $duble = $tmpy; //это просто запомните в дальнейшем пригодится!
```

и делаю манипуляции с выборкой в цикле

```
  while($get = $tmpy->fetch_array()):

 //манипуляции     

  endwhile;
```

но вот второй раз уже отформатировать выборку и сделать с ней что то в цикле через fetch_array я не могу хотя выше продублировал результат выборки $tmpy в переменную $duble

```
 while($gt = $duble->fetch_array()) {
 //ничего не произойдет
 }
```

как быть в таком случае? как это сдлетаь правильно, есть ли способы, кроме как снова посылать запрос к БД такой же как в начале?

Comment: сделайте `fetchAll` и потом просто делайте с массивом всё, что захочется сколько угодно раз......... либо перемещайте указатель в начало http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.data-seek.php

Comment: @АлексейШиманский делаю так $gety = $tmpy->fetchAll(); (потом уже пребераю foreach) НО пишет ошибку  Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetchAll() хотя по мануалу fetchAll от php 5.1 а у меня 5.3 стоит я не так делаю?

Comment: fetch_all по идее http://php.net/manual/ru/class.mysqli-result.php